# Chrome and Internet Explorer doesn't work Offline, works fine on Firefox

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox, web-deployment

Mobile Web Offline browser support problem ----

I am working on mobile web application, when i open web site on mobile and go offline, Firefox works fine. But it doesn't work in chrome and IE browsers. Please help me.......

Comment: Squeeze tight your mobile device untill it screams... Then re-read your own question, and think, if you could improve it some how.

Comment: We need to see some code, or the app/site in question, any error messages, any more details you've got. Otherwise we're helpless to assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you validated the appcache using Firefox?

1. Press shift F2 to bring up the Firefox command line.
2. Go to your site.
3. `appcache clear`
4. `appcache validate`

Comment: seems like theres a typo on the #4 "apcache" ?